# Integral $\int_0^1 \frac{\sqrt{x}}{3+x}\; dx$

Tags: integration

How can we compute integration below?

$$\int_0^1 \frac{\sqrt{x}}{3+x} \;dx$$

Solution shows the answer is 2-π/3 but I can not derive this equation.

Comment: HINT: Change of variables $x=t^2$

Comment: And even, $$x=3t^2$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the substitution: $x=u^2, \, dx=2u\,du$

$$\int_0^1 \frac{\sqrt{x}}{3+x} dx=2\int_0^1 \frac{u^2}{3+u^2} du={\displaystyle\int_0^1}\left(\dfrac{\class{steps-node}{\cssId{steps-node-4}{u^2+3}}}{u^2+3}-\dfrac{\class{steps-node}{\cssId{steps-node-5}{3}}}{u^2+3}\right)\mathrm{d}u={\displaystyle\int_0^1}\left(1-\dfrac{3}{u^2+3}\right)\mathrm{d}u$$
$$={\displaystyle\int_0^1}1\,\mathrm{d}u-\class{steps-node}{\cssId{steps-node-6}{3}}{\displaystyle\int_0^1}\dfrac{1}{u^2+3}\,\mathrm{d}u=1-\class{steps-node}{\cssId{steps-node-7}{\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}}}}{\displaystyle\int_0^1}\dfrac{1}{v^2+1}\,\mathrm{d}v=1-\sqrt{3}\,\arctan\left(\frac{u}{\sqrt{3}}\right)\Bigg|_0^1$$
$$=1-\sqrt{3}\arctan\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)=1-\frac{\sqrt{3}\pi}{6}=\frac{6-\sqrt{3}\pi}{6}$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

Set $t^2=x,\;t\ge 0$ to obtain the integral of a rational function:
$\;\mathrm d x=2t\,\mathrm d t$, $\;x=0\leftrightarrow t=0$, $\;x=1\leftrightarrow t=1$, so
$$\int_0^1 \frac{\sqrt{x}}{3+x} \,\mathrm d x=\int_0^1 \frac{2t^2}{t^2+3} \,\mathrm d t = 2\int_0^1 \Bigl(1-\frac{3}{t^2+3} \Bigr)\,\mathrm d t=\dotsm$$